# Lua 3d table pairs Function returns nil value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua

I have been researching for the past hour and have done it exactly how it should work.

I want to access data in a 3d table in Lua so here is my code:

```
    test_table = {
        info = {
            name = "John",
            age = 25
        }
    }

    for key, value in pairs(test_table) do
        print(test_table.key[value].name)
    end
```

It always gives me an error, that key is a nil value. But if use

```
for key, value in pairs(test_table) do
    print(key)
end
```

it returns info. So I am no sure what I did wrong, and I havent found a solution, so please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_table = {
    info = {
        name = "John",
        age = 25
    }
}

for key, value in pairs(test_table) do
    print(test_table[key].name)
end
```

You were indexing `test_table["key"][the_table]` not `test_table[key]`

Speaking of, you can just use value and avoid a table lookup, since that's also returned.

```
for key, value in pairs(test_table) do
    print(value.name)
end
```